# why does the request.Session context manager doesn't actually close the connection?

Tags: python, http, tcp, python-requests, contextmanager

I have 2 containers, `client` and `server`. In `server`, I started a python SimpleHTTPServer:

```
python3 -m http.server
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
```

on `client`, I started a request to it:

```py
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get("http://172.17.0.3:8000")
```

The server successfully received the request:

```
172.17.0.2 - - [26/Oct/2022 00:17:29] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Now, I am inspecting the state of the TCP connections in `server` using `ss` and `netstat` and I see the TCP connections are still open for a little while before actually getting discarded, even when my python script already finished.

What's the point of opening a `request.Session()` in a context manager, if the connection is going to be left open anyways? According to the [requests documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/):

> Sessions can also be used as context managers:
>
> ```py
> with requests.Session() as s:
>     s.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
> ```
>
> This will make sure the session is closed as soon as the with block is exited, even if
> unhandled exceptions occurred.

This says the `Session` is closed but doesn't really specify that the TCP connection is closed. What's the point of closing the Session, if the TCP connection is going to be left open anyways? Is there a way to close the TCP connection right after the context manager finishes? Is it even recommended?

Comment: The session is intended to keep some sort of common configuration for every request underneath, handle cookies... Look at it as if you were going to interact several times (through several requests) with one specific website that requires login, for instance. And no, it doesn't close (or open) requests on its own. If you want, you can store the request in a variable (`my_req = s.get('https://....')` and close it later `my_req.close()`)

Comment: *"I see the TCP connections are still open for a little while before actually getting discarded"* - what do you mean with "open", what do you mean with "discarded"? It might be useful to have a look at the [TCP state diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tcp_state_diagram.png) to understand what happens after a connection is closed, i.e. moving from ESTABLISHED to CLOSED but passing other states in between.